# Migrating from RC5 to RC6 issue with no exported member

Tags: angular

I have angular 2 code in RC 5 version, I change package.json and updated to RC 6 and after I do that I am getting below errors:

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12258728/18326503/06d5234e-7514-11e6-8457-74a86648a155.png

Comment: As far as the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` and `FORM_PROVIDERS`, those have changed (I thought they did in RC5) to `HttpModule` and `FormsModule`.

I would recommend going back through the QuickStart/Tutorial to see all the things they've updated

Comment: Yes. They are not present in rc5. Are you sure you are migrating FROM rc5? I have an up and running app on rc5 and i have formsmodule and httpmodule.

Answer (score 1):

You want to import the Http and Form providers and directives with `imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule]`